l1 penalized quantile regression on subset of variables
I'm working on $\ell_1$-penalized quantile regression which means that you add an  $\ell_1$-penalty (like in Lasso) to the quantile regression loss. This lets you estimate conditional quantiles of $Y$ given $X$, while shrinking some coefficients to zero for variable selection or regularization purposes. The setup is:
$$
\hat{\beta} = \arg \min_{\beta} \sum_{i=1}^n \rho_\tau (y_i - x_i^\top \beta) + \lambda \|\beta\|_1,
$$
where

$\rho_\tau(u) = u(\tau - \mathbb{I}\{u < 0\})$ is the quantile loss, adjusting the weight of residuals,
$\lambda$ controls the penalty strength, and
$\|\beta\|_1 = \sum_{j=1}^p |\beta_j|$ is the $\ell_1$-penalty which encourages sparsity.

The main reference for the theory on this method is Belloni and Chernozhukov (2011) in the Annals of Statistics.
Let's now suppose that I have certain variables which I do not want to penalize in my model. This means I want to estimate something like this:
$$
\hat{\beta} = \arg \min_{\beta} \sum_{i=1}^n \rho_\tau (y_i - x_{i1}^\top \beta_1 - x_{i2}^\top \beta_2) + \lambda \|\beta_{2}\|_1.
$$
This way, only some variables in $x_{i2}$ are penalized, while the others are not. Is anyone familiar with any theory on this approach? I'm particularly interested in how to show consistency and whether the convergence rates remain the same. Moreover, I'm interested in how to formulate the restricted eigenvalue condition which is standard in lasso proofs.
My question is very related to this post. The only difference is that they are interested in the standard lasso conditional mean model. I'm interested in a conditional quantile model. This makes theory slightly more complicated as there is not a closed-form solution by using projections.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
